# mysql merging columns

Tags: mysql

Say i have the following MySql 'orders' table:

```
id|car|car_qty|speakers|speakers_qty  
1 | 2 |  15   |   5    |   16
2 | 2 |  19   |   5    |   40
```

What is the query to get the following:

```
product|qty
  2    | 15
  2    | 19
  5    | 16
  5    | 40
```

**WITHOUT** using UNION?

Thank you!

Comment: That does not make anything clear. You should explain. Which columns do you want to merge?

Comment: Shakti - car and speakers are id's of products, and _qty are the quantity for each of them. i wish to see a detailing of products and their qty. sorry if i wasn't clear.

Comment: it seems to me thay your tabledef in not appropriate. Why did you create speakers and speakers_qty instead of using a column (0 or 1) telling you if a row was a car or a speaker? In that way you could have appended items (and select them) without any trouble

Comment: You are absolutely right, my table planning was wrong and I'm going to fix that by adding an orders_row table. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a union ALL from the same table... Just need to make sure the column names and data types are the same...

```
select 
      car as product,
      car_qty as qty
  from
      orders
union all
select
      speakers as product,
      speakers_qty as qty
   from
      orders;
```

Comment: Sorry I've forgot to mention that I'm looking for a query WITHOUT UNION. fixed the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT car product,car_qty qty FROM orders
UNION 
SELECT speakers product,speakers_qty qty FROM orders
```

Comment: Sorry I've forgot to mention that I'm looking for a query WITHOUT UNION. fixed the question. Thank you!

Comment: @Israel: why can't you use UNION? Is there a particular reason?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that at the end it will be a much more complicated and dynamic query that will be generated using PHP, and it looks to me that it will be code-wiser to use this approach as the basis instead of multiple UNIONs. I might be wrong :)

Comment: @Israel.. It might be more complicated if you don't use classic feature... Union suits best according to your need.otherwise rethink on table structure.